# Bridge between Android-Java & JavaScript(Webview)

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am developing an Android mobile app and i need to use webview & HTML page & want to communicate between JS & Java class and functions.

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) is what you're looking for.

Essentially you need to do the following:

- Create a `JavaScriptInterface` with methods that you want called.
- Add this to your `webview` by calling:

  `webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");`
- Add JS code on your webpage that calls out to `Android.nameOfYourMethod()`.